# Can we know possible id/name attributes' values of username/password for input tag for all of the websites?

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, web-development-server

I want to implement password manager, for that I want to provide auto-fill functionalities for username and password.

Is there any way I can get the exact field on the webpages (for almost all of the websites!!) ? some of the website uses `<input type="text" id="username">` while some has `id="login-username"`.

How to know all the possible values for id and name attribute for username and password field?

Answer (score 0):

There's no static list of possible ids. Instead, you can attempt to make a best guess by looking for a `<input type="password>` inside of a `<form>`. Within the form you can try to look for the username input, typically `<input type="text">`.